# How to fix "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" error when finding objects in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, reinforcement-learning, valueerror, q-learning

I'm trying to implement a simple Reinforcement Learning algorithm. Basically, the agent is supposed to move from point A of a square grid to point B using Q-learning. I've gotten this to work previously using a simpler model, but now I need to refine it a bit. Basically, I want to store the Q-values generated by the algorithm in a dictionary called (self.)Q, where each key is a state of the agent and each dictionary value is a list with Q-values corresponding to that state. The states are objects of the class State, which has the grid matrix as attribute. However, when I want to check if a state (new_state) is already in the dictionary self.Q (see code below), I get the following error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use >a.any() or a.all()

Why does this happen? I'm basing my code on this article https://medium.com/@curiousily/solving-an-mdp-with-q-learning-from-scratch-deep-reinforcement-learning-for-hackers-part-1-45d1d360c120, in which they don't seem to run into this problem. If think this has something to do with the fact that the states are separate obejcts, but I do not know how to solve this.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
from copy import deepcopy


grid_size = 4
m_A = 0 # Start coordinate in matrix
n_A = 0 # Start coordinate in matrix
m_B = grid_size - 1 # End coordinate
n_B = grid_size - 1 # End coordinate
ACTIONS = ['Right', 'Left', 'Up', 'Down']
eps = 0.1
gamma = 0.7
alpha = 1


class State:
    """Defines the current state of the agent."""
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, State) and self.grid == other.grid

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self.grid))

terminal_grid = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))
terminal_grid[m_B][n_B]
terminal_state = State(terminal_grid)

class Robot:
    """Implements agent. """
    def __init__(self, row = m_A, col = n_A, cargo = False):
        self.m = row # Robot position in grid (row)
        self.n = col # Robot position in grid (col)
        self.carry = cargo # True if robot carries cargo, False if not
        self.Q = dict()
        self.Q[terminal_state] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    def move_robot(self, state):
        """Moves the robot according to the given action."""
        m = self.m # Current row
        n = self.n # Current col
        p = [] # Probability distribution
        for i in range(len(ACTIONS)):
            p.append(eps/4)
        if self.carry is False: # If the robot is moving from A to B
            Qmax = max(self.Q[state])
            for i in range(len(p)):
                if self.Q[state][i] == Qmax:
                    p[i] = 1 - eps + eps/4
                    break # Use if number of episodes is large
        cur_env = deepcopy(state.grid)
        # cur_env = state.grid
        cur_env[m][n] = 0
        action = choose_action(p)
        if action == 'Right':
            if n + 1 >= grid_size or cur_env[m][n+1] == 1:
                Rew = -5 # Reward -5 if we move into wall or another agent
            else:
                n += 1
                Rew = -1 # Reward -1 otherwise
            a = 0 # Action number
        elif action == 'Left':
            if n - 1 < 0 or cur_env[m][n-1] == 1:
                Rew = -5
            else:
                n -= 1
                Rew = -1
            a = 1
        elif action == 'Up':
            if m - 1 < 0 or cur_env[m-1][n] == 1:
                Rew = -5
            else:
                m -= 1
                Rew = -1
            a = 2
        elif action == 'Down':
            if m + 1 >= grid_size or cur_env[m+1][n] == 1:
                Rew = -5
            else:
                m += 1
                Rew = -1
            a = 3
        m = m % grid_size
        n = n % grid_size
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        cur_env[m][n] = 1
        # print(cur_env)
        new_state = State(cur_env)
        if new_state not in self.Q: # Cheack if state is in dictionary
            self.Q[new_state] = np.random.rand(len(ACTIONS))
        return new_state, a

def choose_action(prob): 
    """Defines policy to follow."""
    action = np.random.choice(ACTIONS, p = prob)
    return action

def episode(robot):
    """Simulation of one episode."""
    # Initialize E, S
    E = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size), dtype = int) 
    E[m_A][n_A] = 1 # Initializes position of robot
    S = State(E) # Initializes state of robot
    robot.Q[S] = np.random.rand(len(ACTIONS))
    count = 0
    while robot.carry is False:
        S_new, action_number = robot.move_robot(S)
        m_new = robot.m
        n_new = robot.n
        if m_new != m_B or n_new != n_B:
            R = -1
        else:
            R = 5
            robot.carry = True # Picks up cargo

        robot.Q[S][action_number] += alpha*(R + gamma*max(robot.Q[S_new])               -robot.Q[S][action_number])
        S = S_new
        # print(E)
        # print()
        count += 1

    return count

nepisodes = []
step_list = []

def simulation():
    """Iterates through all episodes."""

    r1 = Robot()
    for i in range(400):
        nsteps = episode(r1)
        nepisodes.append(i+1)
        step_list.append(nsteps)
        r1.m = m_A
        r1.n = n_A
        print("End of episode!")
        print(nsteps)

simulation()
```